# Propagation Constant Expression in a Transmission Line

Tags: electromagnetism, transmission-line, electromagnetic, microwave, wave

let's consider a generic transmission line:
[image]

Its wave vector Kz is equal to:

[image]

where

[image]

Then, I read also that it is true that:

[image]

where does this relation come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> where does [the] relation [\$k_z=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}\$] ​come from?

The variable \$k\$ is used to refer to different things by different authors.

In many texts, \$k\$ (usually with no subscript) is *defined* as the wavenumber of a wave, i.e. the number of waves per unit length. With that definition,

$$k=\frac{1}{\lambda}$$ where \$\lambda\$ is the wavelength.

In the text where you saw, $$k=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$$ \$k\$ is just modified by a convenience factor of \$2\pi\$ just like we use $$\omega = 2\pi f$$.  In that case, \$k\$ is the *phase constant* for a particular sinusoidal wave. It represents the change in phase angle per unit length.

In the equation $$k_z=\sqrt{(R+j\omega L)(G + j\omega C)}$$ \$k_z\$ is the propagation constant for a sinusoidal wave along the transmission line.

The real part of $$k_z = \alpha + j\beta$$ (i.e. \$\alpha\$) is the attenuation factor. It informs us how much a sinusoidal signal is attenuated per unit length.

The \$\beta\$ in the above equation is the phase constant for the wave under consideration. It is identical to the \$k\$ in the equation

$$k=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$$

Thus, when you see in different places,

$$k_z = \alpha + j\beta = \sqrt{(R+j\omega L)(G + j\omega C)}$$

and

$$k=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$$

The \$k\$s mean different (but related) things.

Answer (score 0):

The wavenumber \$k\$ is the result of solving the differential equations of the (general) electromagnetic wave for \$E\$ and \$H\$ in e.g. free space. The result for \$k\$ consists of the material characteristics \$\mu,\epsilon,\sigma\$.

When solving the telegrapher equations for the coaxial cable, you also get \$k\$, but this time \$k\$ consists of an R,L,G & C expression.

So the wavenumber \$k\$ comes either from the definition of a **general** wave or from the definition of a **generic transmission line** like e.g. a coaxial cable.

(The phase constant \$\beta\$ is just the imaginary component of \$k\$.)

Comment: But where does the link k= √(YZ) = k = 2π/lambda? Why are they necessarily equal in case of TEM mode?

Comment: @Kinka-Byo I refined my anwer to give you a bit more insight